# Can I see source code of built-in controls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, open-source

how do i view source code of text box that developed by microsoft in visual studio 2008 while i am programming with c# language in visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 4):

[.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Answer (score 4):

If the text box is part of the .net framwork you can see its source by following theses steps [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sburke/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code)

Answer (score 1):

Reflector is good.  But did you also try using the Microsoft Symbol server?

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sburke/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy(VS.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/21/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-to-step-into-microsoft-net-source-code.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the .NET Framework is not Open-Source and you cannot browse the source code.

You can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to look into the Microsoft Assembly, but you won'ìt have direct access to the raw code.

Comment: source of a part of .Net framework has been released for open access.

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio *2010*, under Tools -> Options -> Debugging, if you enable "Enable .NET Framework Source Stepping" you will be able to do that.

VS will download symbols from the MS symbols server.

Comment: i can not check what yuo said, could you send me a example for testing?????????

Comment: Just debug any projects in VS2010 after enabling the option above, and you will be able to step into Framework code.

Just   Console.WriteLine("Step into me.")   will do.